# J2ME polish - JSON

Tags: json, j2mepolish

Does J2ME polish support org.json.me package?
My polish code doesnot recognise the json jar.
What shall i do?

Kidly help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your build.xml file

```
<libraries>
<library file="${polish.home}/import/json-1.0.jar" />
</libraries>
```